# WordPress FrontPage stuck on About Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that has been stuck on the About page as the front page. I checked the site's admin page and I discovered that the About page had been set as the front page. I set it back to the default posts page but it won't change back. I have tried to clear the cache on the WordPress site as well as on my browser but it still won't change back. I have tried to check the site on other computers but the About page still remains as the front page. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front page can be overridden by your active theme. Check you active theme if there was a front page set on it.

You can also disable your themes to isolate the issue. If the problem reoccur, disable your plugins and if the issue still persist, you need to provide more information about your WordPress installation

Comment: I updated all the plugins and now the rightful homepage has been restored. The Navigation menu has however disappeared. I am poking around the theme to see if I can resolve this... if you have any tips kindly share.

Comment: I love to help but I can't replicate the problem without the same exact theme and plugins.

Comment: Usually the navigation is just a menu slot in /wp-admin/nav-menus.php, maybe the menu was accidentally removed/unloaded